# Can we run background task even app is terminated in iOS

Tags: ios, xamarin, xamarin.ios

I want to run the background task even the application is terminated in iOS.

Is it possible.

If Yes. Can anyone tell how we can achieve this.

Comment: After the app is “terminated” (e.g., the user “force quit”)? No. Or just after the app has just been “suspended” (e.g., the user just way back to the iOS home screen and/or fired up another app)? Yes.

Comment: Below, Lucas mentions `BGAppRefreshTask`, but there is also [`BGProcessingTaskRequest`](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/bgprocessingtaskrequest). It just depends upon what you want to do in this [background task](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks). See [Background execution demystified](https://developer.apple.com/wwdc20/10063).

Answer (score 0):

You could use **Background Tasks** to keep your app alive  when it is terminated . Check the details of [BGAppRefreshTask](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/backgroundtasks/bgapprefreshtask) . Note :it is available after iOS 13.0 . On iOS 12.0 and before you need to use this [API](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/uikit/uiapplicationdelegate/1623125-application) .

To be able to use Background tasks, please, follow these steps:

1.Add the following key to **Info.plist** to enable Background modes:

```
 <key>UIBackgroundModes</key>
 <array>
    <string>fetch</string>
    <string>processing</string>
 </array>
```

2,Add the following key and uniques task ids to **Info.plist**:

```
 <key>BGTaskSchedulerPermittedIdentifiers</key>
 <array>
    <string>com.xamarin.ColorFeed.refresh</string>
    <string>com.xamarin.ColorFeed.cleaning_db</string>
 </array>
```

3.You need to add a unique task id into Info.plist for each background task you want to execute.

For mode details you could check this [Doc](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/samples/xamarin/ios-samples/ios13-refreshingandmaintainingyourappusingbackgroundtasks/) .